# Prove that an Isometric linear operator on a finite dimensional inner product space is Unitary

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I really don't find relevance of being finite dimensional of the inner product in proving an isometric linear operator is unitary.Please help me

Comment: On a finite dimensional space, an injective operator is automatically surjective.

Answer (score 2):

If $T$ is an isometry, then
$$\langle T^*Tx,y \rangle = \langle Tx,Ty\rangle=\langle x,y\rangle$$
holds for every $x,y$. Hence $T^*T=I$. Since the space is finite dimensional, we must also have $TT^*=I$. Therefore $T$ is unitary.

---

This isn't true in infinite dimensions. Indeed, on the Hilbert space
$$\ell^2 := \{x:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{C} \mid \sum_{n=1}^\infty |x(n)|^2 < \infty\}$$
with inner product
$$ \langle x,y \rangle = \sum_{n=1}^\infty x(n)\overline{y(n)},
$$
the "right shift operator" $R:\ell^2\to\ell^2$ defined by
$$R(x)(n)=\begin{cases} 0 & \text{if}\ n=1 \\ x(n-1) & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$
is an isometry that is not even a surjection, and thus not unitary.

Comment: Thank you for helping me it's really helpful to me but the only thing i can't find how to prove that for a finite dimensional inner product space we must have TT*=I for an isometric linear operator T . Thanks again for help

Comment: @AnilKumarPandey I'm happy to help. Since $T^*T=I$, we know that $T^*$ is a left inverse of $T$. This implies on a finite dimensional space that $T$ is invertible and $T^{-1}=T^*$. The fact that $T$ is invertible follows from the fact that, on a finite dimensional space, invertible, injective, and surjective are all equivalent. Then use the existence of $T^{-1}$ to obtain $TT^*=TT^*(TT^{-1})=T(T^*T)T^{-1}=TT^{-1}=I$.